# Use result of selection statement into another selection in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

How can I use the result of a select statement into another statement in a stored procedure in SQL Server? I am try to write this code

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[ShowRequest] (@Id int) 
AS
  SELECT 
     Request.RequestId,
     Request.UserId
  INTO
     reqTable       
  FROM
     [User],[Request]
  WHERE
    Request.UserId = [User].UserId  
    AND
    Request.RequestId = Id

  /*another selection*/
  SELECT
    RequestProduct.ProductName
  FROM
    RequestProduct
    /*ERROR:The multi-part identifier "ReqTable.id" could not be bound*/    
  WHERE      
     RequestProduct.RequestId = ReqTable.[id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[ShowRequest] (@Id int)  

AS 

SELECT  

     Request.RequestId, 
     Request.UserId 

INTO 
    reqTable         
FROM 
    [User],[Request] 
WHERE 
    Request.UserId = [User].UserId   
AND
    Request.RequestId = Id 

/*another selection*/ 
SELECT 
    ProductName 
FROM 
    RequestProduct 
WHERE
    RequestId in
(
    select id
    from reqtable
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you actually just need to do a single selection:

```
SELECT 
     u.RequestId,
     r.UserId,
     rp.ProductName
FROM
    [User] u
        inner join
    [Request] r
        on
             r.UserId = u.UserId  
        inner join
    RequestProduct rp
        on
            rp.RequestId = r.RequestId
WHERE
    r.RequestId = @Id
```

Generally, with SQL, you should decide what overall result you're trying to achieve, and then try to express it as a single statement - SQL Server's job (or any SQL product's) is to work out how best to construct the results. You shouldn't have to break down the problem into separate parts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the etiquette here - this is a comment not a proposed answer but I want to make it easier for people to comment on my comment...  downvote as appropriate... I don't want to just start a new question since I want the OP to see this.

You've got some alternatives but no one talked about why the first query didn't work or answered how to use the results of one query into another.

Why it didn't work: If the table "reqTable" existed and had a column named "id" at the time that your query was evaluated, SQL Server could have bound the name.  You can use "eval" to put in sql that will be valid when it runs.  For this problem that would be unjustifiably complex, but things like this must come up, I don't know if it's a regular tool in the toolbox of people who write a lot of stored procedures.

SQL Server 2005 and 2008 both have a feature called "CTE" you should read about that addresses the general question of "How do I use the results of one query in another query".  They don't do anything subqueries absolutely can't do, but most of the time they are easier to write.

Comment: Apart from CTE's there's also the option to use a temporary table (#hello) which will only be visible to the stored procedure (unless it already existed somewhere along the stack, but using clever naming that shouldn't be a problem) or one could use a table-variable (which has it's own ups and downs). Personally I'm a big fan of temp-tables as (IMHO) it has the least down-sides and allows for pretty much all operations on both small and large data-sets.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. declare a table contains the result of first selection and use it in the second selection.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[ShowRequest] (@Id int) 
AS

DECLARE @reqTable TABLE
(
   ReqID int,
   UserID int
)

INSERT INTO
  @reqTable
SELECT 
 Request.RequestId AS 'ReqID',
 Request.UserId

FROM
 [User],[Request]
WHERE
 Request.UserId = [User].UserId  
AND
Request.RequestId = Id

/*another selection*/
SELECT
RequestProduct.ProductName
FROM
  RequestProduct,@reqTable

WHERE      
  RequestProduct.RequestId = ReqID
```

Thanks for everyone who care about my question and spend his time to solve my problem